# How do I simplify $\frac{(bS)^{2}}{(bS)^{2} + y}$ to $\frac{1}{1+\left[\frac{y}{bS}\right]^{2}}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

As the above mentions I have the fraction $\frac{(bS)^{2}}{(bS)^{2} + y}$ and the next step in the equation I am following simply states "it works out to equal" $\frac{1}{1+\left[\frac{y}{bS}\right]^{2}}$.

I'm sure its simple but I am very rusty on my algebra, do I need to multiply by the conjugate?

I'd be very grateful for a worked example

Thanks in advance

edit: I accidentally wrote - when I meant to put + in both denominators. Below is a clarification of terms.

The initial expression was $\frac{M^{2}}{M^{2}+y}$, where M = bS

edit2: Having checked the paper the text I'm following is based on I have found that the initial expression should have been $\frac{M^{2}}{M^{2}+y^{2}}$, solving  the issues I was having.

Comment: I do not thonk it is true unless some extra conditions are mentioned

Comment: $y^2$ is problematic. $$\frac{(bS)^{2}}{(bS)^{2} + y} \cdot \frac{(bS)^{2}}{(bS)^{2}}$$

$$\frac{1}{1 + \frac{y}{(bS)^{2}}} $$

Comment: I would divide both the numerator and denominator by $bS^2$ ... but there's a problem, the sign of the term involving $y$ would be opposite, yet everything else matches. Like Shamim mentioned, unless there's other conditions/info, I think there's a typo. EDIT: Oh, and the $y$ itself is a problem ...

Comment: Even more than one typo.

Comment: Yeah I'm seeing a bunch of possible problems... @OP - Can you double check the expression, and add any constraints/relevant info on the variables? Also of note now that I see it: there's a difference between $(bS)^2$ and $bS^2$, so which are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I made a couple of typos initially. I have corrected these now and have also clarified that it was $(bS)^{2}$ not $bS^{2}$.

Comment: Then,it would be $\frac{1}{1+\frac{y}{M^2}} = \frac{1}{1+\frac{y}{(bS)^2}}$ and not, $\frac{1}{1+(\frac{y}{bS})^2}$

Comment: So should I assume it is a typo in the text I'm following?

Comment: Still a typo, i think $y$ should be $y^2$

Comment: Having checked the paper the text is based on (Hanski's Incidence Function Model for anyone interested) I have seen that the typo in the text im following is that the initial expression should indeed be $\frac{M^{2}}{M^{2}+y^{2}}$. Sorry for wasting peoples time!

Comment: If you think your problem has been resolved, why not answer your own problem?  This is explicitly encouraged on SE network.

Answer (score 0):

As the good people in the comments suspected, it turns out that the reason I was struggling was because of a typo in the text I was following.

$\frac{(bS)^{2}}{(bS)^{2} + y}$ should have been $\frac{(bS)^{2}}{(bS)^{2} + y^{2}}$

Simplification is therefore a process of dividing both the numerator and denominator by $(bS)^{2}$ to end up with $\frac{1}{1 + [\frac{y}{bS}]^{2}}$